# Is there any dojo ui widget can be used for mic test

Tags: javascript, dojo

I need to create a ui for a web page that can be used for the system mic volume indicator. For eg. when user speaks then based on the volume the indicator shows the bar filled.
I wanted to create that kind of ui using any dojo widget. Do we have any widget that I could readily use ?

**Note:** I'm only looking for a UI help here. We already have a browser plugin that communicates with the microphone.

Comment: slider UI should fit your requirement Link for [tutorial](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/sliders/) and [demo code](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/tests/form/test_Slider.html). You will need to hook your event handler to automatically adjust the slider based on the volume levels.

Comment: Thanks Frank. The dijit slider ui worked well. I had to hide the slider handle using css and I got the expected ui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dijit slider ui worked as frank suggested in the above comment. I had to hide the slider handle using the css and it worked perfectly.
Also I chose slider over the progress bar because I don't need the %age to be shown.

Answer (score 2):

Dijit has a progress bar widget at `dijit/ProgressBar`. I set up a simple example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xm245ajm/). It may work for your needs, as you could update its value whenever you receive an update from your browser plugin that's communicating with the system volume.

Comment: Progress bar also works, however I think the slider is better in the volume indicator case because of 2 reasons. 1) The slider can be divided into parts 2) I don't need a %age shown there.